# Restrict access from group in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I need to restrict access for a few users in Debian 7. I basically only want them to be able to login with their accounts so they can use SSH to forward their web traffic through my server as a proxy.

I created a group and moved them to it.

What would be the best way to restrict as much of their access to files and directories as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change file and directory permissions using `chmod` ("change mode"). Here's a [file access permissions reference](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/file-permissions-reference) - it contains detailed information on changing file/directory permissions for various groups and users.